# Protractor function is a reserved keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, coffeescript, protractor

I'm trying to do a conditional logic in protractor. If this button is displayed, then click the button or else, click something else. **I'm using coffee scripts.**

```
describe 'Create a portal', ->
    it 'Create a Portal', ->
        element(By.css('.portal-col>.btn-primary')).isDisplayed().then(function(result) {
            if(result)
            {
                element(By.css('.portal-col>.btn-primary')).click()
            }
            else{
                element(dropdownPortal).click()
                element(createPortal).click()
            }
        });
```

I get this error:

```
  - SyntaxError: reserved word "function"
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is coffeescript, you need to [correctly declare the promise resolution function](http://coffeescript.org/#literals):

```
element(By.css('.portal-col>.btn-primary')).isDisplayed().then((result) ->
    // ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        element(By.css('.portal-col>.btn-primary')).isDisplayed().then (result) ->
          if result
            element(By.css('.portal-col>.btn-primary')).click()
          else
            element(dropdownPortal).click()
            element(createPortal).click()
          return
```